# One huge XML file with long SQL statement or not?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database with about 10 tables and they are all interconnected in some way(foreign keys, assosiative tables).

I want to use all that data to plot it on my instance of Google Map as markers with infoboxes and be able to filter the map.

Judging from the [Google Maps Articles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/articles) you have to use XML with the data from the database to plot the markers and everything else.

But what would be the right way to generate that XML file? Have a huge SQL statement to generate one XML file with entire data from all tables upon the load of the web-page and the map or is there a more correct approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You in no way have to use XML to place markers on an instance of Google Maps. You **could**, but you don't have to if it seems difficult. I work a lot with the Google Maps V3 API and I would recommend you export your data to JSON and embed it in your document using PHP or make it available for JavaScript to load using Ajax.

Creating interactive Markers from the data is REALLY easy. You just need to iterate over your data, create a Marker object for each point you want on the map, supply some HTML you want displayed in the info window and show that info window on the Marker's click event.

Instead of walking you through with teaspoon accuracy I'll refer you to the [Google Maps API v3 beginner tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) which among other things includes examples of how to create Markers and display them on the map.

Fun fact, you can control which icon is displayed for each marker (you can supply an URL to any image you want), as well as make them bounce. To summarize, you have way more control using JavaScript than if you went with XML.

**Regarding performance**, I would heed cillosis' advice and cache your MySQL data in which ever format you end up choosing. If you were to go with JSON you could cache the result of that as well. You can simply save the output in a file called something like "mysql-export-1335797013.json". That number is a Unix timestamp with which you can extrapolate when the data needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Can't I just generate that one huge XML file with one long SQL statement, then store it on the server and use it to filter the markers on the map with something like XPath and php?

Comment: I steered clear of using XML for Google Maps. Using JavaScript you have all the Markers available in a neat array. Any time you change a filter you just need to iterate through the array and determine which markers shouldn't be visible and run `marker.setVisible(false)` on them. This is assuming that you're just loading ALL the data from the server in the first request. This is what I usually do and it works well performance-wise up to about 10 000 Markers

Comment: What you can do with Javascript has nothing to do with whether the data gets from the server to the client in XML, JSON or any other format.

Comment: Of course, but if you're going to create an interactive map using JavaScript, why would you transfer your data using anything but JSON? Especially XML? Also I'm pretty sure OP was talking about Google's KML format which you can just plug straight into Google Maps. You can do a lot of cool stuff with that, but I still don't think you can reach the same level of control as when you create all markers manually using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL the **first** time to generate the XML for a specific query, and then cache that XML output for later use. The very first time it may be slow, but after that it will already be generated and will be really fast.

Comment: So for each new filter query run an execute sql statement, generate xml and save it to the server and then if anyone else asks for tyhe same filter query just serve them the cached version?

Comment: Exactly. I do something similar with a tide application I have. The data changes every 24 hours so I cache it for that long in case someone makes a request for a tide location again it will be faster. How long your data remains valid depends on you and your application of course.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example to using caching in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XML because PHP and AJAX make it relatively easy, then do. That's why the examples use it. But you are *definitely* not restricted to XML. JSON is commonly used because it's also easy with PHP, a smaller download than XML and delivered in a form which is directly usable by Javascript. Or you could use anything else which can be manipulated by your page's Javascript.

With regard to whether to use one humungous query and data download or not, you don't have to do that either. You could do: it might be slow — not only to do the query but also to transfer the data, where caching the query results won't help. Your users will have to wait for the data to arrive and then be manipulated by your Javascript to appear on the map.

You might consider doing a fairly simple query to get basic data to display so the users get something to see reasonably quickly, following that up with more queries, perhaps as data is required. There is no point in downloading loads of InfoWindow data if the user is not going to click and see it. In that instance, deliver marker data and basic InfoWindow data and only get detailed data if the user actually requests it (that is, use a two-stage InfoWindow).